# Antd form not working properly when i used for updating the records

Tags: reactjs, antd, redux-toolkit

i have a problem with the Antd (version 4) form when I update the data.

```
 export const PostUpdate = () => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const { uuid } = useParams();
 const [form] = Form.useForm();
 const { singlePost } = useSelector(
   (state) => state.post
 );
const { title} = singlePost;
const defaultValues = {
  title,
};
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getPost(uuid));
}, [dispatch, uuid]);

form.setFieldsValue(defaultValues);

return (
  <Fragment>
    <div
      className="site-layout-background"
      style={{ padding: 20, minHeight: "70vh" }}
    >

    <Title level={5}>Update Post : {title}</Title>
    <Form
      layout="vertical"
      form={form}
    >
      <Item
        name="title"
        label="Title"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please enter title of post",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Item>
    </Form>
  </div>
</Fragment>
);
};
```

This is my complete code for the update the data. if I use **form.setFieldsValue(defaultValues)**
outside the useEffect, it's loading the data in the form fields and working fine.

But there is an error in the console(attached an image). when I use **form.setFieldsValue(defaultValues)** inside the useEffect its not working.

Did I miss anything or have I done it wrongly?
Please help me !!

[image]

Comment: Can you create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), remove irrelevant code.

Comment: @slideshowp2 yes i know it's a bit long some are asking about full code. also, some other technologies like redux-toolkit used so don't know because of that I'm getting this issue.

Comment: can you show me the code that you use form.setFieldsValue(defaultValues) inside the useEffect ? or you can create a codesandbox demo ?